# JestClient Get.Builder is failing though SearchBuilder works fine

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

JestClient is returning signature mismatch error while running the query using Get.Builder, though the other queries using SearchBuilder are working just fine.

This works:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("_id", id));
Search search = new SearchBuilder(searchSourceBuilder.toString(), "my_index", "default").create();
return jestClient.execute(search);
```

But NOT this:

```
return jestClient.execute(new Get.Builder("my_index", id)
            .setParameter("preference", "_primary").type("default").build());
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should probably show some code, it'll help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @Val, updated my question with sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

After updating `aws-signing-request-interceptor` version from 0.0.16 to 0.0.22 in pom.xml, the issue got resolved, but I'm not sure why `Get.Builder` only failing with 0.0.16 version (by the way I'm using `elasticsearch` dependency of version `5.5.2`).

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>vc.inreach.aws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-signing-request-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.22</version>
       </dependency>
```